# Ubuntu 18 Log on override

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

Just installed Ubuntu 18.  First thing I notice.  I must enter my password every time I start up.  Did not have to do that with 16.  I don't need the security.  Can I set up the computer so I am always logged on?

Answer (score 0):

Searching for [ubuntu auto login](https://www.google.com/search?q=ubuntu+auto+login), google automatically displays this at the very top:

> ### Log in automatically
>
> 1. Open the Activities overview and start typing Users.
> 2. Click Users to open the panel.
> 3. Select the user account that you want to log in to automatically at startup.
> 4. Press Unlock and enter your password.
> 5. Toggle the Automatic Login switch to ON.
>
> [Log in automatically - Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/user-autologin.html.en)
>   https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/user-autologin.html.en

They even have a picture, looks like it's from KDE:
[image]

Next time, don't forget to try a search first.